# PHP SimpleXML - getting value

Tags: php, mysql, simplexml

I am trying to use SimpleXML with PHP to get a value from XML stored in a database. A portion of my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_161" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
  <object class="atavism.agis.objects.AgisMob" id="AgisMob0">
  <void property="name">
    <string>Rachels</string>
  </void>
  <void property="oid">
  <object class="atavism.server.engine.OID" id="OID0">
  <void property="data">
    <long>41321</long>
  </void>
```

I also have other XML in the same "document" that looks like this:

So that being said, I would probably need to fetch it where the property attribute is equal to "name". I do plan on getting other information from this document later on as well, just need to figure out how.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$blob_query = mysqli_query($dbh8, "SELECT * FROM objstore WHERE obj_id='$characterId' AND type='PLAYER' AND namespace_int='3' ORDER BY obj_id DESC LIMIT 1");           
        if($blob_query){
            $blob_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($blob_query);
            $data = $blob_row['data'];

            $xml=simplexml_load_string($data) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            echo $xml->void[0]->string;

        }
```

It is not displaying anything. It should be displaying "Rachels". Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the full XML please? (Just cut too long node if you want). We cannot help you with a _"portion of my XML"_. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the question to include up to the long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `<object>` tag to get `<string>` tag content.

Assuming you XML look likes (as a valid XML):

```
$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_161" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
  <object class="atavism.agis.objects.AgisMob" id="AgisMob0">
      <void property="name">
        <string>Rachels</string>
      </void>
  </object>
  <void property="oid">
      <object class="atavism.server.engine.OID" id="OID0">
          <void property="data">
            <long>41321</long>
          </void>
      </object>
  </void>
</java>';
```

You have to use:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($data) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->object->void[0]->string;
```

outputs:

```
Rachels
```

Note also that `[0]` is not necessary (in this case):

```
echo $xml->object->void->string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try insert all elements in container like

```
<?php 
$xmld = '
<obj>
<void property="data">
  <long>41321</long>
</void>
<void property="datad">
   <long>413213</long>
</void></obj>';
 $xml=simplexml_load_string($xmld) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo $xml->void[0]->long;
```

Comment: The whole XML is within <java></java> tags, so it technically is already in a container.